# How to create and delete public files using scoped storage, Android Q

Tags: android, delete-file, q, scoped-storage

We have an app that sends MMS messages.  The Android MmsManager requires a URI parameter that points to a file.  It seems this file needs to be public, or the MmsService gets an Io exception for Permission denied.  So in conforming with new scoped storage rules I create a .dat file in the MediaStore DownLoads folder.  This works fine, even if storing .dat files in the MediaStore doesn't make sense to me.  But after the MMS message is sent, I need to delete this file.  I can't see any way of doing this without asking the user for permission, or using android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.  Asking the user for permission to delete files he doesn't even know about is obviously not good.  And of course android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE requires permission from Google to use, and seems overkill just to be able to remove a data file that was created by the app.  So, is there any way to create a public file that can later be deleted.  I am already aware of android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" which is a very temporary solution, and Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory which is deprecated. The file is created using code similar to below.  pdu is a previously created byte array.

```
final String fileName = "send." + String.valueOf(Math.abs(mRandom.nextLong())) + ".dat";
    ContentResolver contentResolver = mContext.getContentResolver();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

    Uri contentUri = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), contentValues);

try {
     writer = mContext.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(contentUri);
     writer.write(pdu);
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error writing to output stream in MmsSender. e= ", e);
    } finally {
        if (writer != null) {
            try {
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "IOException writing PDU file in MmsSender, e= " + e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "It seems this file needs to be public, or the MmsService gets an Io exception for Permission denied" -- did you try using `FileProvider`? "Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory which is deprecated" -- FWIW, [it is undeprecated in Android 12L and is safe to use](https://commonsware.com/blog/2021/11/06/about-environment-undeprecations.html), though it does not increase your access rights.

Comment: Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory will give me a list of path names. I can then create File objects and then call delete.  
File f = new File(path); f.delete(); 
So this will solve my problem.
I'm interested in FileProvider.  I looked at the documentation.  It seems to work for granting privileges to other packages, or in Intents.  But I'm simply passing the urii as an argument to a method,
 smsManager.sendMultimediaMessage(context, uri, ...
Is there anyway to grant privileges in this case.  It really doesn't makes sense to be storing these files in a public storage area.

Comment: Another comment on my own question.  The main reason for deleting the files is to save storage space, since they are somewhat large.  Media Store doesn't seem to provide for this, but it will let you open output streams to the files.  So I can just overwrite the files with nothing in them, when I'm done with them, so they're not taking up any space.  Then I'll just reuse the same files.

Comment: "It seems this file needs to be public, or the MmsService gets an Io exception for Permission denied" -- I am assuming that this means that you tried `Uri.forFile()` to some file in `getExternalFilesDir()` and that it failed. If that is not what you tried, try that. "Is there anyway to grant privileges in this case" -- not easily. Your situation is similar to [notification ringtones](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/09/07/notifications-sounds-android-7p0-aggravation.html). The "scalpel" and "axe" solutions that I describe there may be valid for your use case.

Comment: I would probably go with the "axe": implement a `ContentProvider` that does not require permissions (so the SMS stuff can read the content) and takes other steps to ensure that nothing else can access the content (only honor `Uri` values that you generate with random data in the path, and put a reasonable time limit in place for how long you will hold onto the content). My apologies for not realizing that `FileProvider` would not work in your case -- I haven't dealt with MMS much.

Comment: I'll look at your  notification ringtones. No apologies needed,  just because FileProvider doesn't work for this case doesn't mean it isn't something  I should know about.  Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I'm having the same issue despite using a ContentProvider to serve the PDU file.